# Added fonts to Stimulsoft Designer resorces fall back at render

Tags: stimulsoft

I have added a few fonts to the resources of the mrt file like so:

[image: Font resources]

And used them for some texts.

The font are applied in the designer and the preview tab, but at runtime they fall back to another font.

How do I fix this?